# How to split a query result in to multi pages (pagination) and sort query data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, activerecord

In my model I get the entire `order` table.

```
return $this->db->get('order')->result();
```

In my view i do a `foreach` to loop through the data.

```
<?php foreach ($orders as $order) : ?>
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $order->id; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $order->order_status; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $order->cart; ?></td>
     . . . 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Ok so that works like a charm. However I need to be able to do some data arranging here.

1. I want to be able to sort records by `id` so that I can get the latest on top
2. I want to split the results (pagination) say every 25 records and add the (go to next page link)

I'm using **Codeigniter** and building on the MVC pattern. So is their a library perhaps or built-in functions in `CI` that allow me accomplish these 2 objectives? I appreciate all helpful advice, code examples and general guidance. Thank you in advance for your time! :)

**Edit 1**

Sorry I didn't mention this.. Can someone give me an example of how the `query` needs to be structured `return $this->db->get('order', 25)->result();` isn't exactly giving me the desired result here.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a created_at column and sorting by that rather than ID.  You can't guarantee that data will be added in chronological order (i.e. combining two systems' data, backups, etc).

Comment: the id is `AI` so that will work fine in my case. I need more assistance with regards to the `query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Datatables jquery plugin along with server side implementation , There is already an implementation of datatables wrapper class for code ignitor below is the link for the repository

It is called Ignited dataTables

[Ignited datatables at github](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables)

You can fork the above repository and try out with your needs

and also using [datatables](http://datatables.net/) has another advantage , you can specify server side calls for almost all nice to have functionalities

such as search in table , pagination , sorting , etc

EDIT : - After looking at your edit , I found that you are also having problem in fetching data in server side , Here is the codeignitor model function , Put this function in the model class and instantiate and call in your model .

Pass limit and sort by columns names appropriately

```
function getResult($limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order) {

        $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        $sort_columns = array('id', 'title', 'category', 'rating', 'price');

            // set default column name to sortby as per your need 
        $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'title';

        // results query  
            // Change column names as per your need 

        $q = $this->db->select('id, title, category,  rating, price')
            ->from('Order')
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

        $ret['rows'] = $q->get()->result();

        // count query
        $q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
            ->from('Order');

        $tmp = $q->get()->result();

        $ret['num_rows'] = $tmp[0]->count;

        return $ret;
    }
```

Comment: nice i like the added functionality. Will check that out. thanks! :)

Comment: Yep, Datatables is one of the best thing i ever used!

Comment: Dude, I was just checking it out and playing with the functionality and I am convinced that I will be implementing this! Very cool. Thanks!

Comment: Just nervous about the functionality on non JS enabled browsers. Need to do some more research. But this earns the check mark. Thanks!

Comment: Any ways @fabio I have now posted a server side model class function also to query and get result , you can use it if you find it difficult to implement

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code to get the query results with pagination:

```
<?php
/*
    Place code to connect to your DB here.
*/
include('config.php');  // include your code to connect to DB.

$tbl_name="";       //your table name
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
$adjacents = 3;

/* 
   First get total number of rows in data table. 
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "filename.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 2;                                 //how many items to show per page
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT column_name FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">� previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>";   

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next �</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
?>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    // Your while loop here

    }
?>

<?=$pagination?>
```

add this in your css file:

```
div.pagination {
padding: 3px;
margin: 3px;
}

div.pagination a {
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin: 2px;
border: 1px solid #AAAADD;

text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
color: #000099;
}
div.pagination a:hover, div.pagination a:active {
border: 1px solid #000099;

color: #000;
}
div.pagination span.current {
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000099;

    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #000099;
    color: #FFF;
}
div.pagination span.disabled {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;

    color: #DDD;
}
```

hope it helps..
Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use codeIgniter's Pagination class,which  is very easy to use, and it is 100% customizable, either dynamically or via stored preferences....

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Goin through pagination class will help u for ur 1) question too... or else u can use order by  in ur query.

Comment: Yeah I know about that. But I'm having trouble structuring the `query` which returns the results

Comment: Okay I found the latest edit just now wait let me try to post the query here

Comment: have u tried $this->db->get('order', 25 ,0)...
The second and third parameters enable you to set a limit and offset clause..

Comment: is it 25 => max and 0 => min ? What exactly is offset? Thanks btw. NVM i see what offset does. I can't imagine why that would be useful in any circumstance..

Comment: @fabio 25 is the page limit and offset is the starting record number... if you click on page two,the offset will be 25 now..clicking on page 3 makes it 50

Comment: @fabio that's how pagination works.. and if you set `$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;` the offset will be page numbers like 2,3,4..etc

Comment: +1 for the info - So hang on if what you're saying is `('order',25,0)` will show record 1-25 on page 1 and then 25-50 on page 2? So if i want 26-51 on page two i would have to do `('order',25,1)` is that what you meant?

Comment: @fabio offset is the id.. so,page 1 shows you 0-24,page 2 shows 25-49.. You shouldn't give ofset directly.. Pagination class generates them

Comment: ok so by not giving it directly you're saying `('order',25,0)` or `('order',25,$offset)` $offset being a var returned from pagination class (if that exists) or just simply `('order',25)` with nothing set for offset?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18030/discussion-between-bhuvan-rikka-and-fabio)

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using codeigniter custom library pagination look these pages.

http://phpmaster.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html